# where to save and how to use a jks certificate in Android

Tags: android, ssl, android-xml

Im using Jsoup to pull in xml, and while i have it working in java using

```
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/Users/EK/web2.uconn.edu.jks");
```

this code wont work in Android. I know i need to store the certificate somewhere in the android project, but where would i save it/how would i reference it? If someone else knows a different way to establish an ssl connection without jsoup that is fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` to get HTTP content. If you need a custom trust store, you can store it as a raw asset, load it into a `KeyStore` and use that to initialize a [SocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html), which you use to initialize the `HttpClient`.